# How to choose 3 paths for data to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this site http://www.heresourwedding.com The site is actually a poker league website just using a spare url I had. Anyway, I have a database connected to it so I can add scores to a leaderboard.
I can't figure out how to add scores to 3 paths.
So If I add scores to adddurack.php the scores get updated and put into the table on leaderboarddurack.php. Then I have to do the same to addoverall.php and playeroftheweek.php.
is there a way I can add scores to just adddurack.php and the scores go to addoverall and playeroftheweek. This will save me time so I am not adding the same scores to 3 differant pages all the time.

the code for durplayers.php is here

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
include "dbconnect.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['points']))
    {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $points = $_POST['points'];
        $sql = "SELECT username,points FROM durack WHERE username='".$user."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        //update the points
        if($numrows!=0)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {   
                $username=$row['username'];
                $oldpoints=$row['points'];
            }

            $totalPoints = $oldpoints + $points;

            $sql1 = "UPDATE  durack SET points='".$totalPoints."' WHERE username='".$user."'";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql1))
            {
                header("Location: AddDurack.php?added=Points");

            }
        }
            // Add player and Points
        else 
        {
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO durack(`username`,`points`) values ('$user',$points)";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql2))
            {
                header("Location: AddDurack.php?added=PlayerAndPoints");

            }

        }

    }
    else 
    {
        header("Location: AddDurack.php?added=mandatory");

    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

to login I have set up a username and password for you guys
user:   user5
password: password

the player of the week table is name potw
and the addoverall table is called players,
on the database...
thanks.

Comment: Sorry, to login go to any leaderboard page and click on the red spade at bottom of page.

Comment: Remember to use prepared statements in production code